# Bash regex for strong password

Tags: regex, bash, input, passwords

How can I use the following regex in a BASH script?

```
(?=^.{8,255}$)((?=.*\d)(?!.*\s)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]))^.*
```

I need to check the user input(password) for the following:

1. at least one Capital Letter.
2. at least one number.
3. at least one small letter.
4. and the password should be between 8 and 255 characters long.

Answer (score 3):

If your version of `grep` has the `-P` option it supports PCRE (Perl-Compatible Regular Expressions.

```
grep -P '(?=^.{8,255}$)(?=^[^\s]*$)(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])'
```

I had to change your expression to reject spaces since it always failed. The extra set of parentheses didn't seem necessary. I left off the `^.*` at the end since that always matches and you're really only needing the boolean result like this:

```
while ! echo "$password" | grep -P ...
do
    read -r -s -p "Please enter a password: " password
done
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm don't think that your regular expression is the best (or correct?) way to check the things on your list (hint: I'd check the length independently of the other conditions), but to answer the question about using it in Bash: use the return value of `grep -Eq`, e.g.:

```
if echo "$candidate_password" | grep -Eq "$strong_pw_regex"; then
    echo strong
else
    echo weak
fi
```

Alternatively in Bash 3 and later you can use the `=~` operator:

```
if [[ "$candidate_password" =~ "$strong_pw_regex" ]]; then
    …
fi
```

The regexp syntax of `grep -E` or Bash does not necessarily support all the things you are using in your example, but it is possible to check your requirements with either. But if you want fancier regular expressions, you'll probably need to substitute something like Ruby or Perl for Bash.

As for modifying your regular expression, check the length with Bash (`${#candidate_password}` gives you the length of the string in the variable `candidate_password`) and then use a simple syntax with no lookahead. You could even check all three conditions with separate regular expressions for simplicity.

Comment: `echo-weak` should be a new tag... to go beside `it's-always-friday-in-iceland`

Comment: Thanks for the comment but I need this to be done in bash as I have a script that does a lot of other things.

Comment: Well obviously you can call `ruby` or `perl` from your Bash script if that's not a problem, similar to calling `grep`. Or if you mean pure Bash, use the `=~` (assuming you can assume Bash 3.x minimum), but you'll need to modify your regular expression (same for `grep`).

Comment: I don't want to use Perl if possible and I haven't been able to use the above regex(which works in Java btw) in BASH. I have BASH 4.

Comment: Use a different regular expression. The absolutely simplest way is to use three different ones: `[a-z]`, `[A-Z]`, and `[0-9]`.

Answer (score 1):

These matches are connected with the logical AND operator, which means the only good match is when all of them match. 
Therefore the simplest way is to match those conditions chained, with the previous result piped into the next expression. Then if any of the matches fail, the entire expression fails:

```
$echo "tEsTstr1ng" | egrep "^.{8,255}"| egrep "[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]"| egrep "[abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"] | egrep "[0-9]"
```

I manually entered all characters instead of "[A-Z]" and "[a-z]" because different system locales might substitute them as [aAbBcC..., which is two conditions in one match and we need to check for **both** conditions.

As shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh
a="tEsTstr1ng"
b=`echo $a | egrep "^.{8,255}" | \
             egrep "[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]" | \
             egrep "[abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"] | \
             egrep "[0-9]"`
# now featuring W in the alphabet string
#if the result string is empty, one of the conditions has failed
if [ -z $b ]
  then
    echo "Conditions do not match"
  else
    echo "Conditions match"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

`grep` with `-E` option uses the Extended regular expression(ERE)
From this [**documentation**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html) ERE does not support look ahead.

So you can use Perl for this as:

```
perl -ne 'exit 1 if(/(?=^.{8,255}$)((?=.*\\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])|(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[^A-Za-z0-9])(?=.*[a-z])|(?=.*[^A-Za-z0-9])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])|(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[^A-Za-z0-9]))^.*/);exit 0;'
```

[**Ideone Link**](http://www.ideone.com/IrYN5)

Answer (score 0):

I get that you are looking for regex, but have you consider doing it through PAM module?

- [dictionary](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man8/pam_cracklib.8.html)
- [quality](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man8/pam_passwdqc.8.html)

There might be other interesting modules.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I would like to keep my script simple  and I don't want it to be dependent on another module or a programming language like Perl.